# Setting all dictionary elements to 0 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary full of numbers:

```
{1:10, 2:5, 3:18, 4:0, 5:1}
```

All I want to know is, how I could set all these values to zero, without changing each individual element? So it would be like:

```
{1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0}
```

I'm not used to using dictionaries yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place:

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2:5, 3:18, 4:0, 5:1}
>>> for k in d:
...     d[k] = 0
... 
>>> d
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Comprehension and (optional) reassignment:

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2:5, 3:18, 4:0, 5:1}
>>> d = {k:0 for k in d}
>>> d
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another (fairly strange) way to do it:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(d.keys(), 0)
```

Comment: Don't you just love strange answers? +1

Comment: It's better in general to call the classmethod on `d` itself - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> d = {1: 10, 2: 5, 3: 18, 4: 0, 5: 1}
>>> d.update({k:0 for k in d})
>>> d
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

An even stranger way to do it

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2:5, 3:18, 4:0, 5:1}
>>> d = d.fromkeys(d, 0)
>>> d
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

The advantage this answer has is that it can return an object of the same type as `d` in the case that `d` is some mapping other than `dict`. eg.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict()
>>> d.update({1:10, 2:5, 3:18, 4:0, 5:1})
>>> d.fromkeys(d, 0)
defaultdict(None, {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the dictionary keys and an iterator of infinite zeros and then create a dictionary like so:

```
dict(zip(d, itertools.repeat(0))) # create a dict using the zip of the keys and some zeros
```

Comment: No need to use `d.keys()`, just zip with `d`. This avoids making a temporary list if you are using python2